# Why is this BFS queue returning None?

Tags: python-3.x, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I am currently attempting the Hackerrank problem called [Castle on the Grid](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/castle-on-the-grid/problem),
in which I have implemented a BFS in Python 3 as follows:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
from collections import deque

def minimumMoves(grid, startX, startY, goalX, goalY):
    n = len(grid)
    queue = deque()
    queue.append((startY,startX))
    goal = (goalY,goalX)
    turnsMatrix = [[0]*n]*n

    while queue:
        current = queue.popleft()
        (Y0, X0) = current
        print(current)
        d = turnsMatrix[Y0][X0]

        if current == goal:
            return(d)

        for X in range(X0-1,-1,-1):
            if grid[Y0][X] == 'X':
                break
            elif turnsMatrix[Y0][X] == 0:
                turnsMatrix[Y0][X] = d + 1
                queue.append((Y0,X))

        for Y in range(Y0-1,-1,-1):
            if grid[Y][X0] == 'X':
                break
            elif turnsMatrix[Y][X0] == 0:
                turnsMatrix[Y][X0] = d + 1
                queue.append((Y,X0))

        for X in range(X0+1,n):
            if grid[Y0][X] == 'X':
                break
            elif turnsMatrix[Y0][X] == 0:
                turnsMatrix[Y0][X] = d + 1
                queue.append((Y0,X))

        for Y in range(Y0+1,n):
            if grid[Y][X0] == 'X':
                break
            elif turnsMatrix[Y][X0] == 0:
                turnsMatrix[Y][X0] = d + 1
                queue.append((Y,X0))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    n = int(input())
    grid = []

    for _ in range(n):
        grid_item = input()
        grid.append(grid_item)

    startXStartY = input().split()
    startX = int(startXStartY[0])
    startY = int(startXStartY[1])
    goalX = int(startXStartY[2])
    goalY = int(startXStartY[3])
    result = minimumMoves(grid, startX, startY, goalX, goalY)
    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')
    fptr.close()
```

However, despite only one return statement which is supposed to return an `int` d, my code returns a `None`. I know that the `deque` eventually becomes empty and returns `None`, but I am having trouble figuring out why things stop appending to the queue.

For the test case

```
3
.X.
.X.
...
0 0 0 2
```

I noticed that what would happen is:

1) castle moves right and breaks at X.

2) castle moves down one cell, **and the turns matrix becomes**

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]].
```

3) `queue` becomes `deque([(1, 0)])`.

4) A None is returned.

What is going on? I've been staring at my code for days and I'm going crazy... please help, thank you!

Comment: It means you got to the end of the queue without finding the `goal`, there is an implicit `return None` at the end of the function, which means the `while` loop completed.

Comment: @AChampion hi, could you give me a hint as to why nothing is appended to the queue?